# How can I find a devise user by it's session id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

Given `session["session_id"]` is it possible to find the logged in `User` to which that session belongs to?

Comment: You can use User.current_user instead... did you tried?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

At least on my system (rails 3.2, devise 2.0.4), you can do it like this:

`session` is:

```
{"session_id"=>"be02f27d504672bab3408a0ccf5c1db5", "_csrf_token"=>"DKaCNX3/DMloaCHbVSNq33NJjYIg51X0z/p2T1VRzfY=", "warden.user.user.key"=>["User", [3], "$2a$10$5HFWNuz5p6fT3Z4ZvJfQq."]}
```

`session["warden.user.user.key"][1][0]`, then is `3`.

So, I'd find it as:

```
User.find(session["warden.user.user.key"][1][0])
```

Comment: On Rails 4.2.1, Devise 3.4.1 you'll want to use User.find(session["warden.user.user.key"][0][0])

Comment: Thanks. This example is ugly, but it work. Thanks again. This example for cookies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43549108/5754223

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but will try to answer

If you want only the User from the current session, a simple way would be to store his id on session, for example:

```
def login(username, pass)
  # do the usual authentication stuff and get user
  if logedin
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

Then get the current user would be something like

```
current_user =User.find(session[:user_id])
```

---

If what you want is finding all the users that are currently logged in, I think you need to config your app to save session at DB, because predefined is that session data is store in cookies in the browser. For more information on this check this answer
[How to track online users in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586499/how-to-track-online-users-in-rails)

---

**EDIT:** Just noticed you are using devise so the first way is actually there for you. You just need to call `current_user` method at any controller.
For the second way check this answer ["Who's Online" using Devise in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504130/whos-online-using-devise-in-rails)

Answer (score 2):

And i might add this, as i was trying to do it the other way, if you are using ActiveRecord session_store you can find all stored sessions of a user like so:

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.select{ |s| s.data["warden.user.user.key"] && s.data["warden.user.user.key"][0][0] == user_id }
```